# Lower bound for The chromatic index of the complete graph of order n, where n is odd.

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

How can I prove that the chromatic index i of the complete graph of order n, where n is odd, is i > n-1.
I found here a construction with n colors, but am having a hard time to prove lower bound.

Comment: I'm speaking about the odd order n, where the chromatic index is n, I want to prove you cant edge color with less than n colors.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. fixed it. Apologies.

Comment: Why If you edge color Kn with n−1 colors, then there must be at least n/2 edges of one color? and why if n is odd, there must be at least (n+1)/2 edges of one color?

Comment: I believe you have typing mistake and you meant that " If the number of purple edges is <=n/2" right?

Comment: I understood what you said, everything but these 2 things:
1) when you say "of one color" do you mean that there is at least one color that it hold for it, or that it holds for any color?
for example: If n is odd, there must be at least (n+1)/2 edges of one color. does it mean there is one color with at least (n+1)/2 edges or that for any color there are at least (n+1)/2 edges?
2) what do you mean by "If two vertices can't share an edge, those (n+1)/2 edges must have a total of at least n+1 vertices."?

Comment: Got you. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Assume by contradiction that you can color $K_n$ with $n-1$ colors. Then, at each vertex each color appears exactly once.

Now, pick one color, and draw the subgraph of all edges of this fixed color. This is a subgraph on $n$ vertices, where each vertex has degree 1. But this is not possible by handshaking lemma, since $n$ is odd.

**P.S.** Alternately, pick one color and show that it only appears at an even number of vertices (i.e. the number of vertices having an incident edge of that color is even). Therefore, this color is missing at one vertex, and that vertex has n-1 edges. [think in terms of sports: n teams tournament, each team plays at most a game per day, colors=days. On day 1 a team must have a bye, and still n-1 games left]